# Split list os strings and integers in single elements or rows ith the same ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want have rows with a list of elements, at first i had a DataFrame with this structure:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════╦════════════╦══════════╦═════════════╗
║ url                               ║ date       ║ name     ║ numMentions ║
║ www.newspaperarticle              ║ 2018-12-31 ║ Bill     ║ 2           ║
║ www.newspaperarticle              ║ 2018-12-31 ║ Cosby    ║ 3           ║
║ www.newspaperarticle              ║ 2018-12-31 ║ New York ║ 1           ║
║ 
╚═══════════════════════════════════╩════════════╩══════════╩═════════════╝
```

I changed it into a structure where the words in name and numbers in numMentions are attached once to the IDS url/name by grouping them:

```
 df.groupby(['url','date'], as_index=False).agg({
    'name': lambda x: list(x),
    'numMentions': lambda x: list((map(str,x))),
    'avgSalience':lambda x: list((map(str,x)))
})
```

And i got the following DataFrame:

```
╔══════════════════════╦════════════╦═══════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ url                  ║ date       ║ name                  ║ numMentions ║
║ www.newspaperarticle ║ 2018-12-31 ║ [Bill,Cosby,NewYork]  ║ [2,3,1]     ║
╚══════════════════════╩════════════╩═══════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

What i want is either being able to access the single words in the list, because currently the list is just an element with all the words or a struchture like below:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════╦════════════╦══════════╦═════════════╗
║ url                               ║ date       ║ name     ║ numMentions ║
║ www.newspaperarticle              ║ 2018-12-31 ║ Bill     ║ 2           ║
║                                                ║ Cosby    ║ 3           ║
║                                                ║ New York ║ 1           ║
║ 
╚═══════════════════════════════════╩════════════╩══════════╩═════════════╝
```

[Here is an example of the Data with 10 rows](http://www.filedropper.com/auszugstack)

Comment: So what exactly is your desired result looking like?

Comment: see the last Table, i want all,names and the numMentions attached to one url/date or be able to acces the single words in my list as my groupby function isnt working as intended @JvdV

Answer (score 1):

After your groupby, you can use the Pandas Series string function "join" which works just like python str "join".

```
df.name.str.join(' ')
```

And:

```
df.numMentions.str.join(' ')
```

This will get you the values, you just have to reassign it to the Series in question.

**Edit**

This worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'url': ['www.newspaperarticle', 'www.newspaperarticle', 'www.newspaperarticle'],
    'date': ['2018-12-31', '2018-12-31', '2018-12-31'],
    'name': ['Bill', 'Cosby', 'New York'],
    'numMentions': [2, 3, 1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
grouped = df.groupby(['url','date'], as_index=False).agg({
    'name': lambda x: list(x),
    'numMentions': lambda x: list((map(str, x)))
})
names = grouped.name.str.join(' ')
numMentions = grouped.numMentions.str.join(' ')
new = grouped.assign(name=names, numMentions=numMentions)
print(new)
```

This yields:

```
    url                     date        name                numMentions
0   www.newspaperarticle    2018-12-31  Bill Cosby New York   2 3 1
```

Comment: I tried that but that didnt work as intended, it applied to my url/date column bot not the name/numMentions one